# "Trying to get property of non-object" error in Twitter API - users/lookup

Tags: php, api, twitter, error-handling

I try to get 5000 followers with "friends/ids" and "users/lookup" requests.
But program breaks with error message: "Trying to get property of non-object" in this line

```
$user = $twitter->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?user_id=". $ids);
```

How I can fix it?

```
 <?php

    include ('twitteroauth/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');

    define ('CONSUMER_KEY', 'xxx');
    define ('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'xxx');
    define ('OAUTH_TOKEN', 'xxx');
    define ('OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET', 'xxx');

    $twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET);


    $param1 = array(
            'screen_name' => 'twitter',
            'stringify_ids' => true,
            'count' => 5000,
        );

    $data =  $twitter->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/ids.json?", $param1);

    $n = 0;
    $m = 100;

    for ($i=0; $i < 50; $i++) {
    $k = 0;
    for ($j=$n; $j < $m; $j++) {
    $temp_array[$k] = $data->ids[$j];
    $ids = implode (', ', $temp_array);
    $k++;
    }
    $user = $twitter->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?user_id=". $ids);

    $n = $m;
    $m += 100;
    }

    echo json_encode($data->ids);
    print "\n";
    echo json_encode($user->screen_name);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that $twitter actually is an object?

Comment: This request working without problem 
$data =  $twitter->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/ids.json?", $param1);
And I get all ids.